# Spring <context:component-scan base-package="groupid.aop"/> cannot be defined

Tags: spring, maven, spring-aop, maven-dependency-plugin

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"


       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd

        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"

        >

<bean id="triangle1" class="groupid.aop.triangle">
<property name="name" value="triangle bean"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="circle1" class="groupid.aop.circle">
<property name="name" value="circle bean"></property>
</bean>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="groupid.aop"/>

</beans>
```

im getting error on `<context:component-scan base-package="groupid.aop"/>`
 this line. im using maven to add dependencies for both spring and aop dependencies. I also added namespace for context. please let me know if im missing anything.

Comment: I dont' see the context.xsd location in `xsi:schemaLocation declaration`

Comment: I added those lines , im still facing issue. please check the updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were wrong in namespaces declaration.
This xml should solve the issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd          
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <bean id="triangle1" class="groupid.aop.triangle">
        <property name="name" value="triangle bean" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="circle1" class="groupid.aop.circle">
        <property name="name" value="circle bean" />
    </bean>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="groupid.aop" />
</beans>
```

In your original XML you have:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd          
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd    
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"
```

As you can see you declared twice spring-beans (`http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd` and `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd`) and you used the 3.0 context version (`http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd`)

I hope it's usefull

Angelo